# Fortran modules and C++ with Eigen

Tags: c++, fortran, eigen

I am a Fortran user and a complete newbie to C++ and Eigen. I use modules in Fortran to be able to keep my variables, arrays and matrices in different groups and use them as needed. How to implement the idea of modules in Fortran in C++ so that I am able to pass on the data between different subroutines? I cannot paste the entire Fortran code as it is too large and there will be many new concepts which I would like to write directly in C++. Perhaps, a sample snippet or document showing how to pass on the information between C++ routines could be useful. I want to do something like this (and much more) in C++:

```
!*************************************************************************
!  **** module file: module.f95 ****
module global
save
integer, allocatable :: kod(:,:)
end module

module local
save
integer, allocatable :: kode(:)
real*8, allocatable :: func1(:)
integer pts
end module

module fileunits
save
integer,parameter :: file1 = 11, file2 = 12
end module
!*************************************************************************

! Main program
program main

use global
use local
use fileunits

implicit none

int i,j,k,n

open(unit=file1,file='input.dat')
open(unit=file2,file='output.dat')
read(file1, *) n,pts
allocate(kod(n,pts))
allocate(kode(pts), func1(pts))
do I = 1, n
   read(file1, *)  (kod(i,j),j=1,pts)
   do J=1,pts
      kode(j) = kode(i,j)
   end do
   call proc1
   write(file2,*)  ((func1(j), j =1, pts)

end do


end program

subroutine proc1
use local

implicit none
int j

do j=1,pts
   funct1(j) = kode(j) * kode(j)
   ...
   ...
end do

end subroutine
```

Comment: Hello, welcome. Always use the tag fortran. You can add a version specific tag if the question is specific too.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Are you starting to program in C++ only and do you want to know how to do something like modules in C++ (use namespaces)?

Comment: @Vladimir: Yes, I will be coding only in C++ and want to know how do I code in C++ something like modules that are used in Fortran.

Comment: As I said look for namespaces. Or try to rewrite the question so that it is more clear what you want and to attract more C++ programmers. The title suggests you must know both Eigen and Fortran to be able to answer and the fact is you do not.