# C++ assert when accessing Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

This is following a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28050812/4474902) I had asked on Stackoverflow. I try to use namespaces in C++ along with eigen library. This is what I have coded:

```
// test.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include <cstdlib>
#include "goo.h"
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;
using namespace goo;
//    
int main()
{
   void foo();
   foo();
}

// Let foo be a function which operates on an array "myarray" which I want to define in namespace goo
void foo()
{
   int i;
   int j;
   cout << "Enter N:" << endl;
   cin  >> N ;

   for (i=0; i<N; i++)
   {
      for(j=0; j<N; j++)
      {
         myarray(i,j) = i*j;
      }
   }

 }
```

and the goo.h file is:

```
using namespace Eigen; 
namespace goo
{
   int N;
   MatrixXi myarray(N,N); // I want to define a N x N myarray matrix here using the eigen library
}
```

After running this for N=2, I receive:

```
$ foo.exe
Enter N:
2
Assertion failed!

Program: c:\Test\foo.exe
File: C:/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h, Line 337

Expression: row >= 0 && row < rows() && col >= 0 && col < cols()

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I am a newbie to both C++ and Eigen but I suspect that the matrix myarray is not being allocated before I try to put values in it inside a for loop. How do I make sure the value of N entered is passed on to the goo namespace so that myarray is properly initialized and I can use the matrix inside a for loop or somewhere else.

Comment: This has nothing to do with namespaces, you'll have the same issue without them.

Comment: At the time `Matrix` is defined, the value of `N` is zero. You'll need a different approach to initialize it.

Comment: `myarray.resize(N,N);` once you know N.

Comment: Please read a book (you can not change a global variable and assume a dependent global variable is changing, too (N and myarray). More precisely, these exist in each translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

In namespace `goo` you define `N` without initializing it, then pass that value to the `MatrixXi` constructor.  That `N` is not the same `N` that you declare inside `foo()`.  You will need to declare them in the same scope to do what you want to do.